# I want to show status with order when i search order by created_at date using laravel

Tags: laravel

currently i am working on order report i am fetching all order records but except status i have last_status column id which is defined by id with every order but i want to show status with order please help me how can i do that ? Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

**status codes**

```
        '0'   =  'Pending',
        '1'   = 'Info Received',
        '2'   =  'In Transit',
        '3'   =  'Out for Delivery',
        '4'   = 'Failed Attempt',
        '5'   = 'Delivered',
        '6'   =  'Exception',
        '7'   =  'Expired',
        '8'   =  'Canceled',
        '9'   =  'Void',
```

**reportController**

```
public function report(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [];

        // sets the start date at index 0 and ending date at index 1
        $date = explode(' - ', $request->date);

        $Order = Order::with('users');
        $order = $Order->whereBetween('created_at', $date)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();

        $data = [
            'orders' => $order,
        ];
        // return $data['orders'];
        return view('cms.reports.report-list', $data);
    }
```

**html view**

```
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Order Id</th>
                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Order Received Date</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($orders as $order)
                <tr>
                 <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
                 <td>{{$order->users->fname ?? null}} {{$order->users->lname ?? null}}</td> 
                 <td>{{$order->last_status}}</td>

                  <td>{{$order->created_at}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way...

**in order model class**

```
public function orderStatus()
    {
        switch($this->order_status){
          
             case '1':
                return 'Info Received';
                break ;
             case '2':
                return 'In Transit';
                break ;     
            default:     
             return 'Pending';
        }
   
}
```

**in view**

```
  {{ $order->orderStatus() }}
```

**solution with html markup**

**in order model class**

```
public function orderStatus()
    {
        switch($this->order_status){
          
             case '1':
                return '<span class="label label-warning">Info Received</span>';
                break ;
             case '2':
                return '<span class="label label-info">In Transit</span>';
                break ;     
            default:     
             return '<span class="label label-danger">Pending</span>';
        }
```

**in view**

```
  {!! $order->orderStatus() !!}
```

**and css class**

```
.label {
 color:white;
 display:inline-bolck;
 paddign:3px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:25px;
 min-width: 50px;
}
.label-info{
    background:blue;
}
.label-danger{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having to add a `CASE` statement every time you query, you could add the status to a config file and reference from there.

`config/orders.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'status' => [
        0 => [
            'label' => 'Pending',
            'color' => 'grey',
        ],
        1 => [
            'label' => 'Info Received',
            'color' => 'teal',
        ],
        2 => [
            'label' => 'In Transit',
            'color' => 'blue',
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

create a blade component:

`resources/views/components/status-label.blade.php`

```
<span
    class="text-sm font-medium bg-{{ config('orders.status.'.$status.'color') }}-100 py-1 px-2 rounded text-{{ config('orders.status.'.$status.'color') }}-500 align-middle">
    {{ config('orders.status.'.$status.'label') }}
</span>
```

Then in your blade file, you can do:

```
<x-status-label :status="$order->last_status" />
```

Comment: thank u so much sir but please i have one question please can you tell me ?

Comment: how can i show different colors on status please guide me

Comment: I have updated my answer to add color support. Please check!

Comment: my page is not showing when i use this code <x-status-label :status="$order->last_status" />